# passing function as parameter

Tags: javascript

I got two functions, passing one of then as parameter, like:

```
var a = function(f)
{
  // some code
  f();
};

var b = function()
{
};

a(b); // works great, the function a is executed, then the function b is executed
```

Now I need to extend it to tree functions, like:

```
var a = function(f)
{
  // some code
  f();
};

var b = function(f)
{
  // some code
  f();
};

var c = function()
{
};

a(b(c)); // but it does not work. b(c) words like a method and get executed right on the instruction.
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a callback kind of pattern. Instead of simply passing along the results of the functions, you would do something like so:

```
var a = function(callback)
{
    // Do Stuff
    callback();
}

var b = function(callback)
{
    // Do Stuff
    callback();
}

var c = function() { }
```

Your code would end up looking like so:

```
a(function()
{
   b(function()
   {
       c();
   });
});
```

Effectively, you pass along another function to execute after the method finished. In the above scenario, I simply supply two anonymous functions as the callback arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Pass a wrapper function that executes `b(c)`:

```
a(function() {
    b(c);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function a(f){
  // code
  f()
}
function b(f){
  // code
  a(f())
}
function c(){
  //code
}

b(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an anonymous function:

```
a(function() { b(c); });
```